# absolute extrema problem....

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

My calc skills are kind of rusty.  Was wondering if I could get an assist on this one perhaps?  I am looking for the absolute extrema if they exist and all the x values they occur at in the domain.  Can someone explain this to me with a graph and the steps so I can see the process?

$$
f(x)=x\sqrt{4-x^2}, ~~~[-2,2]
$$

I have worked out how to find the derivative I think. I just wanted some one to double check my math, and steps if possible?

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=x\sqrt{4-x^2}\\
&=\frac d{dx}(x)\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)+x\cdot\frac d{dx}\left(4-x^2\right)\cdot x\\
&=1\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)+\frac1{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}\left(4-x^2\right)(x)\\
&=\sqrt{4-x^2}+\frac{-\frac d{dx}\left(x^2\right)\cdot x}{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}\\
&=\sqrt{4-x^2}-\frac{2x\cdot x}{2\cdot\sqrt{4-x^2}}\\
(x)&=\sqrt{4-x^2}-\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}
\end{align}$$

OK...
So I have taken the time to do the other steps and wrote them out.  I wanted to see if you guys think I am on the right track with how I came to the solution.  Thanks for your help thus far!  This has helped!  Sorry about the chicken scratch again!

I first solved the equation for zero with the following algebra:
[image: solving for zero]

Then I considered the original function and plugged those values back into the function and came up with the following:
[image: plug into original equation considering given intervals]

I think that this is correct because my graphing calculator confirms this, but I just need confirmation of my steps, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1. A continuous function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ achieves a maximum/minimum.
2. There are two kinds of points in $[a,b]$, interior points $(a,b)$ and boundary points $\{a,b\}$.
3. For $f$ differentiable, if an extremum occurs at an interior point, it must be that $f'(x)=0$ at that point.

Thus for differentiable functions on $[a,b]$, to find the minimum and maximum we know that it occurs either somewhere that $f'(x)=0$ or maybe at $a$ or $b$ (regardless of whether $f'(a)=0$ or $f'(b)=0$).

Thus we should calculate $f'(x)$ and solve for where it is zero to get possible points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ where the max/min may occur. Then we should compare the values $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n),f(a),f(b)$. Then the biggest of these numbers is the maximum of $f$ and the smallest is the minimum of $f$.

I'll help you get started, write $f(x)=x(4-x^2)^{1/2}$, then by the product rule (and chain rule) 
$$
f'(x) = \sqrt{4-x^2} + x\cdot \frac12(4-x^2)^{-1/2}\cdot (-2x) = \cdots
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I am having a hard time I think with the exponent of -1/2.  How do you proceed?

Comment: Recall that $x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$ and $x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}$. Thus $x^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{x^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to get started typesetting math. `$\sqrt{3}$` will render $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I was also wondering too above, where you set it up, is there supposed to be a set of brackets around some of that multiplication to set up order of operation?

Comment: Wondering if you could take a look at the work I completed above towards the first derivative to let me know if I am on the right track with it?  Thanks

Comment: @CaptainConfused Your first derivative is correct.  However, not all the steps look correct. \begin{align*} f(x) & = x\sqrt{4 - x^2}\\ f(x) &  = x(4 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\ f'(x) & = \sqrt{4 - x^2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (4 - x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot -2x\\ & = \sqrt{4 - x^2} - \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4 - x^2}} \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks!  I used your steps to clean up my steps!  I also did more steps past this point, so I am curious to know if my figures and steps to solving are correct.  Thank you!